# Failed runing Selenium test in TC(Linux), but ok for local machine in windows

Tags: java, selenium, automation, teamcity, gradlew

I get the following error **when I run with command: `./gradlew clean runTests`**

> Local on windows: OKI
>   On TeamCity in Linux: .driverSetUp FAILED
>                         java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> INFO[newLocalDriver] INFO Creating driver with options 
>   ro.automation.canalLaDistanta.Achizitie_DeviceSTD.driverSetUp FAILED

This is my code.

```
public WebDriver newLocalDriver() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", getChromeDriverPath());

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(getChromeBinaryPath());

    options.addArguments("--no-default-browser-check");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1280,960");
    options.setHeadless(false);
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");

    log4j.info("Creating driver with options");
    ChromeDriver localChromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    log4j.info("Driver created: " + localChromeDriver);
    return localChromeDriver;
} 

private String getChromeDriverPath() {

    String chromeDriverPath = null;
    System.out.println(operatingSystem);

    if (operatingSystem.contains("windows")) {
    chromeDriverPath = "resources/browser/chromeDriver-windows/chromedriver.exe";
        System.out.println("+++ Windows ChromeDriver found! +++");
    } else if (operatingSystem.contains("linux")) {
        chromeDriverPath = "resources/browser/chromeDriver-linux/chromedriver";
        System.out.println("+++ Linux ChromeDriver found! +++");
    } else System.out.println("OS does not match with Windows or Linux");

    return chromeDriverPath;
```

Comment: @Sanip While editing questions please avoid using the `<blockquote>` markup for the errors as they gets word-wrapped and debugging the error becomes difficult.

Comment: Sure, will keep that in mind.

Comment: Linux by default have not `linux virtual video device`. that's why selenium cannot run. configure Linux OS or use `selenium/hub`